# does throwing Exception kills thread in node js?

Tags: node.js

as I know node js is single threaded, so if I write

```
throw new Error()
```

somewhere in method, it should kill the current thread, so will shut down the whole process?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reading the NodeJs [documentation about exceptions](https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html) helps you understand quite easily what happens.

On the section [Error Propagation and Interception](https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_error_propagation_and_interception) you can read the following:

> Node.js supports several mechanisms for propagating and handling
>   errors that occur while an application is running. How these errors
>   are reported and handled depends entirely on the type of Error and the
>   style of the API that is called.

And answering to your question:

> Any use of the JavaScript throw mechanism will raise an exception that
>   must be handled using try / catch or the Node.js process will exit
>   immediately.

So basically any unhandled exception will kill the whole node process.

That's where tools like [PM2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2) kick in, restarting your node application whenever that happens.

Although [this](http://shapeshed.com/uncaught-exceptions-in-node/) is from 2012 I think it's a nice article and quite simple to understand what should you do with uncaught exceptions